# "?" mark in C macro definition

Tags: c

I got a line in the generic code of stm32f0 so often and I can't get it clearly. what does it mean by the line below. I know its complicated to understand this way. But my point is the **question mark(?)** in the define. Can somebody explain that.

```
#define assert_param(expr) ((expr) ? (void)0 : assert_failed((uint8_t *)__FILE__, __LINE__))
```

Comment: `?:` is the conditional operator. Somebody refers to it as the ternary operator.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

Comment: If you use assert_param(a), this macro will do nothing if a is non-zero, but print an error, if it is. The a ? e1 : e2; is an alternative form of if (a){ e1; }else{ e2; } A macro like this is frequently used to assert a pointer is not a null-pointer (which is zero-valued). It may also be of the form (!!a) ? e1 : e2; to normalize a.

Comment: is it too hard to search for C operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a short form of condition, 
you can write

```
int k = (i > j) ? i : j;
```

this will asign i to k if `i > j` else it will asign j.
this is the way we choose between two options inside a macro

Answer (score 1):

Here a conditional operator is used .
It says if expr is true then the value of the Macro assert_param(expr) will be zero or otherwise
it will call another macro or function assert_failed() with two parameters as input . 
1st is **FILE** macro which is the filename from which the macro has been called and another is **LINE**
macro which is the line number in the file from where the macro has been called.

The conditional operator format is like this:

```
a?b:c
```

It means if a is true then b will be the result otherwise c will be the result. 
Accordingly you can separate these statements in the expression.